# Weird behaviour in custom generic class and reflection in Java

Tags: reflection, java-8

I have this custom generic class

```java
@Component("box")
public class Box<T> {
    private T t; // T stands for "Type"

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    
    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Box{" +
            "t=" + t + '}';
    }
}
```

In service class I have this method :

```java
@Component("compo")
public class TempService {

    public Box<String> boxMeth(Box<String> stringBox) {
        System.out.println(Objects.nonNull(stringBox));
        System.out.println("Inside boxMeth!!!!!!");
        //System.out.println(stringBox.get());
        return stringBox;
    }
    
}
```

Inside main I have the following code using reflection :

```java
TempService tmp = (TempService)apcon.getBean("compo");
tmp.testMethod("1");
Box<Integer> box = (Box)apcon.getBean("box");
box.set(10);
Class classObj = tmp.getClass();
Object obj = classObj.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
Method postHookMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod("boxMeth", Box.class);
postHookMethod.invoke(obj, box); // getting allowed because of forceful action by reflection
    
//tmp.testMethod(new Box<Integer>()); // not allowed
```

Now I know as bosMeth method allows Box of type String and by this line `tmp.testMethod(new Box<Integer>())` I am trying to pass an Integer type compiler is throwing error.

But when I am setting value by reflection complier is allowing it. More interesting if I keep this line commented `//System.out.println(stringBox.get());` compiler is not throwing any error.

So my questions are:

1. How can `Box<String> box` can hold an object of type `Box<Integer>` when I am trying to pass the argument by reflection?
2. If the value can be held then why there is an exception from this line `//System.out.println(stringBox.get());` ?

Comment: Not a java expert by any means, but the method `boxMeth` call likely initially succeeds due to generic type erasure, and then the internal call to `System.out.println` fails because it doesn't accept an `Integer` parameter.

Comment: Thats what I thought of but seeking for detailed explanation...

Comment: Matthew is right about [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Since on the byte code level, the method `boxMeth` just receives a `Box` instance and the erased return type of its `get()` method is `Object`, the compiler inserts a type-cast between the the calls `stringBox.get()` and `println(String)`